# Where Did Wormtail Hide Voldemort's Wand?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Is there verification either in canon or from J.K. Rowling as to where Wormtail hid Voldemort's wand during the thirteen years Voldemort was disembodied? I've read through the chapters *The Death Eaters* and *Priori Incantatem* in *Goblet of Fire* and either I missed it, it's in another part of the book/in another *HP* book, JKR's addressed it, or it's unknown. Google didn't yield a satisfactory answer and I don't trust the *HP* Wiki to be fully accurate. So, I'm left with the question: **Where did Wormtail hide Voldemort's wand while Voldemort was in spirit form?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Christiana:** How did voldemort get his wand back after he was in was exile
>   **J.K. Rowling:** Wormtail, desperate to curry favour, salvaged it from the place it had fallen and carried it to him. I admit that would have been a bit of a feat for a rat, but they are highly intelligent creatures!
>   (src: [J.K. Rowling and the Live Chat](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html), Bloomsbury.com, July 30, 2007)

This doesn't directly answer the question, but it does NOT talk about "keeping" it at all - which, unless JKR misspoke, means that it likely wasn't hidden anywhere by Wormtail while Voldemort was in spirit form - it was salvaged once he was about to give Voldemort a real body in GoF.

Having said that, it seems that Animagi keep their own wands once they un-transform (as well as their cloths), so it's not impossible for Pettigrew to have "kept" Voldemort's wand the same exact way.

Comment: Well, I doubt that Wormtail salvaged it during GoF - because I really doubt that after so much time the Ministry didn't examine the area in search for clues of whatever happened there. As a minimun, he salvaged it immediately after the accident.