# How do wizarding criminals obtain wands?

Tags: harry-potter

Sirius gets a wand during the Battle of the Department of Mysteries in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, but how is this possible since Sirius is an escaped convict from Azkaban? The same goes for all the escaped Death Eaters that broke out of Azkaban. Plus how did Voldemort get his wand back in *Goblet of Fire*. Didn't the wand get lost in the rubble in the Potter's house?

Comment: Voldemort is directly addressed by JKR: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/how-did-voldemort-get-his-wand-back There's a more general question, though no explicit canon support for the answers: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66732/how-do-the-azkaban-escapees-get-their-wands-back

Comment: Note the total absence of security at Ollivander's shop. There are wands in the windows, on display shelves and right by the doors.

Comment: Wild that an expulsion from a school can result in wand destruction, but a sentence to Azkaban by the Wizengamot results in confiscation, **just in case they're innocent**.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: @Aww_Geez: I actually like that. Better for systems to have features that recognize mistakes can be, and are, made. Wand destruction for a young wizard who isn't fully trained, mentally immature, and hasn't yet proved their value to society seems fitting (within the fictional world) since they are more likely to indulge in risky behaviors. They can always go to Ollivander's again should they ever be cleared - the stories certainly don't have a one-and-only-soulmate type of thinking about wands. Someone in prison is fully trained, very used to their wand, and probably did some good once.

Comment: I always thought they bought them on the Black-Arts Market.